# How to pass all routes to a single controller in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an OWIN hosted app that does 2 things:

1. Provides an API at `mydomain.com/api/...`
2. Routes ALL other requests to a single controller that returns an HTML page

I currently have this route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "default",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Index" }
);
```

And this controller:

```
public class IndexController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        string html = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/www/.../index.html");
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(html),
            StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
        return response;
    }
}
```

This works fine when I go to my home route:

```
mydomain.com => HTML
```

How can I configure the route template so that I always go to the same controller?

```
mydomain.com/path1 => I want the same HTML
mydomain.com/path1/something => I want the same HTML
mydomain.com/path2 => I want the same HTML
mydomain.com/path3/somethingElse => I want the same HTML
etc
```

What I want seems so simple... I don't care if it's a GET, POST, whatever. Unless the route starts with `api/` I want to return a single HTML page.

Is there a good way of achieving this with web API?

=== EDIT

I am also using static files - so the path to the static files system should be ignore explicitly:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("StaticFiles", "Public/{*url}");
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create separate routes. One for the `API` and a catch all route for all other paths

```
//mydomain.com/api/...
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "api",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Service" }
);


//mydomain.com/path1 => I want the same HTML
//mydomain.com/path1/something => I want the same HTML
//mydomain.com/path2 => I want the same HTML
//mydomain.com/path3/somethingElse => I want the same HTML
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "default-catch-all",
    routeTemplate: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Handle" }
);
```

The controller can handle the request as desired.

```
public class IndexController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Handle(string url) {
        string html = File.ReadAllText(@"C:/www/.../index.html");
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, html, "text/html");
        return ResponseMessage(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that there was already an instance of HttpResponseMessage available. This doesn't work for me though - I get a 404 error

Comment: If I instead make the wildcard {*url} then the I don't get a 404, but every request gets caught (including /api/...) by the Index controller

Comment: @ZachSmith that was a typo on my part. Fixed. The catch all will catch all routes that do not map to a controller via the previous route. Also the order in which you register the routes is important. That is why I showed it in the order I did in the answer

Comment: This is definitely not working. Are you sure that you can use ordering of routes? every request I make with this configuration returns the index.html

Comment: i.e. requests to /api/... are not being caught by the first route

Comment: catch all route should not be the first route. The first route in my answer will catch all routes prefixed with `/api/`

Comment: ahh. the reason is that I'm serving CSS/JS/etc from the file server.

Comment: so routes to /Public/css/style.css are being caught by the catch all

Comment: @ZachSmith That is information outside of what was provided in the original question. To quote what you wanted `Unless the route starts with api/ I want to return a single HTML page.`

Comment: sorry. i didn't realize - but yes - your solution is working perfectly now

Comment: in any case. i would say that a feature of web api could be to ignore explicitly created file servers when routing!